# Querying latest date for a particluar attribute where it is not in date format

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to set up a query that allows me to pick the most recent updated record within a group. If two records have the latest update, then the one with the longest update history should be picked.  If both are null, or both have the same length of history, then neither should be chosen.  The fields are varchar2 format.  The last two digits in first record and last record correspond to the years those records were taken.  The letters in the history length correspond to codes for what type of data was taken.  Below is a sample table, with the expected results:

```
| group_id  |    id |   First Record  |  Last Record    |     History Length    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   a       |    1  |  record98       |    record16     | SNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOE   |
|   a       |    2  |  record97       |    record14     | AVNDAWEDSPSEDSYS      |
|   b       |    3  |  record96       |    record15     | BVNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOE  |
|   b       |    4  |  record98       |    record16     | UNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOP   |
|   b       |    5  |  record95       |    record16     | UNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOPHYE|
|   c       |    6  |  record96       |    record12     | BVNDAWEDSPSEDSYSE     |
|   c       |    7  |  record10       |   record15      | HUSIKD                |
|   d       |    8  |    null         |      null       |            null       |
|   d       |    9  |    null         |      null       |            null       |
|   e       |   10  |  record11       |  record16       |    ASIKSO             |
|   e       |   11  |  record11       |  record16       |    SIXLLO             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output

```
| group_id  |    id |   First Record  |  Last Record    |     History Length    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   a       |    1  |  record98       |    record16     | SNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOE   |
|   b       |    5  |  record95       |    record16     | UNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOPHYE|
|   c       |    7  |  record10       |   record15      | HUSIKD                |
```

The history isn't as important as the latest record, so if that is too difficult to implement, I just need the one row with the latest record.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if the below query works for your requirement.

```
SELECT group_id,ID,first_record,last_record,history_length
FROM (
      SELECT group_id,ID,first_record,last_record,history_length,diff,
             MAX(LENGTH(history_length)) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) max_len,
             count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id,LENGTH(history_length)) cnt
      FROM (
           SELECT  group_id,ID,first_record,last_record,history_length,
                   count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id,LENGTH(history_length)) cnt,
                   MAX(to_date(to_number(substr(last_record, 7,2)),'RR')-to_date(to_number(substr(first_record, 7,2)),'RR'))   OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) diff
           FROM (
                 SELECT group_id,ID,first_record,last_record,history_length,
                        MAX(last_record) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) max_last_record
                 FROM  t
                 WHERE nvl(first_record,last_record) IS NOT NULL
                 )
                 WHERE last_record=max_last_record
           )
           WHERE   (to_date(to_number(substr(last_record, 7,2)),'RR')-to_date(to_number(substr(first_record, 7,2)),'RR'))=diff
      )
WHERE cnt=1
AND   LENGTH(history_length)=max_len;
```

Comment: I am getting an 'invalid number' error.  I am using Toad, and it is highlighting the REPLACE in 'REPLACE(last_record,'record')-';  Those fields are varchar; is there anyway to convert them to date and then base the query on that?

Comment: Try this to fetch number from the column. REGEXP_REPLACE(last_record,'[[:alpha:]]')

Comment: I tried (REPLACE(to_number(substr(lastrecord, 7,2)).  It seemed to work.  Is there anything different from this and what you suggested?

Comment: If lastrecord contains numbers on 7th and 8th position then your trick will also work.

Comment: For the most part, this worked; however I ran into an issue.  One record was from 98-16, while the other was from 10-16.  In this case, we wanted the 98-16 record (since it's longer), but it picked the shorter one.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I've updated my answer to take care of the issue which you have mentioned. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find hemalp108's answer hard to follow; I prefer to break each step down.

Below is how I did this using CTEs, where each subsequent CTE is the next step with a descriptive name i.e.

- Add Max LastRecord
- then Search by Max LastRecord
- then Add HistoryTally
- then Add Max HistoryTally
- then Search by Max HistoryTally
- then Add HistoryTally Frequency
- then Search by HistoryTally Frequency
- then return the result

P.S. SQLFiddle wasn't working so I had to so this in local SQL Server (don't have local Oracle) and tried to translate it back!

```
WITH YourTable AS 
( SELECT * 
    FROM ( VALUES ( 'a',1,'record98','record16','SNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOE' ),
                  ( 'a',2,'record97','record14','AVNDAWEDSPSEDSYS' ),
                  ( 'b',3,'record96','record15','BVNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOE' ),
                  ( 'b',4,'record98','record16','UNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOP' ),
                  ( 'b',5,'record95','record16','UNDAWEDSPSEDSYSEAOPHYE' ),
                  ( 'c',6,'record96','record12','BVNDAWEDSPSEDSYSE' ),
                  ( 'c',7,'record10','record15','HUSIKD' ),
                  ( 'd',8,null,null,null),
                  ( 'd',9,null,null,null),
                  ( 'e',10,'record11','record16','ASIKSO' ),
                  ( 'e',11,'record11','record16','SIXLLO' )
) AS T ( group_id, id, FirstRecord, LastRecord, HistoryLength ) ),

AddMaxLastRecord AS
( SELECT *, MAX( LastRecord ) OVER ( PARTITION BY group_id ) MaxLastRecord
     FROM YourTable ),

SearchByMaxLastRecord AS
( SELECT group_id, id, FirstRecord, LastRecord, HistoryLength
     FROM AddMaxLastRecord
   WHERE LastRecord = MaxLastRecord ),

AddHistoryTally AS
( SELECT *, LEN( HistoryLength ) AS HistoryTally
     FROM SearchByMaxLastRecord ),

AddMaxHistoryTally AS
( SELECT *, MAX( HistoryTally ) OVER ( PARTITION BY group_id ) MaxHistoryTally
    FROM AddHistoryTally ),

SearchByMaxHistoryTally AS
( SELECT  group_id, id, FirstRecord, LastRecord, HistoryLength, HistoryTally
    FROM AddMaxHistoryTally
   WHERE HistoryTally = MaxHistoryTally ),

AddHistoryTallyFrequency AS
( SELECT *, COUNT( HistoryTally ) OVER ( PARTITION BY group_id ) AS HistoryTallyFreq
    FROM SearchByMaxHistoryTally ),

SearchByHistoryTallyFrequency AS
( SELECT group_id, id, FirstRecord, LastRecord, HistoryLength
    FROM AddHistoryTallyFrequency
   WHERE HistoryTallyFreq = 1 )

SELECT * 
  FROM SearchByHistoryTallyFrequency;
```

Comment: So, how would I want to use this code if I can't populate the very top part (I have over 300,000 reocrds?  I am relatively new to sql and that kind of threw me off.  Is 'YourTable' the table I am using now, or the table that I create from 'AS T' right before the AddMaxLastRecord?

Comment: Sorry, yes, just take out the whole `T AS ... VALUES` part and start with `WITH AddMaxLastRecord AS ( SELECT <struff> FROM <your actual table name here>...`